# Code results in no column heading but I want to add "Total Sales"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following line of code which results in the desired output I want

```
summary = df.groupby(df['Year'])['revenue'].sum()
```

Output

```
  Year
    2014    1,199
    2015    1,311
    2016    51,896
    2017    396.94
    2018    87.80
    2019    32.52
```

However, notice there is no column heading over the amount column.  How can I add one in?

Comment: df.groupby('year').agg({'revenue': 'sum'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of groupby series, i.e. `['revenue']`, pass the array

```
# note the double bracket
summary = df.groupby(df['Year'])[['revenue']].sum()
```

Comment: thanks that worked.  What exactly is the rationale behind adding another set of brackets?

Comment: `groupby()['revenue']` represents a series, so you would get a series back, which is why you don't get the column heading, instead you would get a `name: revenue` below the print out. `groupby()[['revenue']]` represents a one-column dataframe, so you would get a dataframe back